# jQuery POST works locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I just moved all my jQuery `POST`s to external files. So I changes `Url.Action` to an actual URL:

```
$(".performance-box").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Performance',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // Unrelated Stuff
        }
    }
});
})
```

This URL does not work on the server because it is a relative path, correct?

So, I changed it to `~/Home/Performance`, but now that does not work locally.

Any guidance on how to approach this in an external file would be helpful.

Comment: Are they on the same server? Remember a relative path is relative to the current directory you're in.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The file structure should be the exact same on the server as it is when I run it on localhost.

Comment: first place to start is inspecting the actual request in network tab of browser dev tools - F12. Should also implement an error handler in your ajax

Comment: Just resulting as a 404 - Usually I use put it in an `Html.Hidden` so I can access it from the external file, but tried to use an actual path this time

Comment: ~ is a server command, wont work there.  Try Moe's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the Url.Action("controller","action") in a global js variable in your view then use it in your external JS this is how I would do it. 
Since you might host your site locally in the default web site which is not the case in production. Using the Url Action will assure that you will have the correct URL.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init();
    });

    function init() {
        url = '@Url.Action("Controller", "Action")'
    }
</script>
```

External JS

```
 $(".performance-box").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // Unrelated Stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need quotes around the @Url.Action

Comment: This worked, but I had to assign a value to `url` without declaring it (so its global) in order to access it in the external file

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the route without the tilde (~) as long as your routes are configured properly in MVC.

C#

```
    //controller class attributes
    [RouteArea("admin")]
    [RoutePrefix("users")]

    //method
    [HttpGet, Route("autocomplete", Name = "Admin_Users_AutoComplete")]
    public JsonResult Autocomplete(string q)
    {
          //do autocomplete
    }
```

Jquery:

```
    ajax: {
        url: "/admin/users/autocomplete",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: true
    }
```